# get value of a textbox a resource dictionary xaml / vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Well i have a little resource dictionary and a little class which manages the code behind, here is the code:

```
  <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MyResources">
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <TextBox Name = TB_1  textchanged="handle_text" Margin="10,50 />
        <Button Name="BT_1" Content="test1" Margin="10,10" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The dataTemplate is displayed in a other class in a contentcontrol, that runs properly.

But in the class MyResources, i would like to get the text value of the textbox TB_1 with the handle_text function when the event textchanged is risen but it seems that the class MyResources doesn't see the variable textbox with the name TB_1 (and all others variables).
Is it possible to do this?

I give you thanks for your help.

Comment: This all sounds incredibly wrong... what are you *actually* trying to do and why do you think that you should do it in a `Resource` file and not in a `UserControl`?

Comment: I just would like to get the value of the textbox in my resource dictionary...Typically if i add click="handle_button" it is ok i can write a function in the class MyResources which handles the event. But what i want is to write a function in my class MyResources to get the text value of my textbox...

Comment: OMG... really? I *can* read, you know... Obviously, I'm *not* asking you to repeat what you put in your question. I'm asking *what are you actually trying to do that for*? Also please answer my other previously asked questions that you ignored.

Comment: Please i am novice in vb.net i just want to have an answer to my question, i don't understand what you mean...I just need to get the value of my textbox, is it possible or not? I need the value to pass it to another function!

Comment: I was trying to help you, but you apparently won't help me to help you, so goodbye.

Comment: So does someone know how to get the value on a textbox in a dictionary resource?

Comment: What @Sheridan wants to know is "Why is it in a DataTemplate ?". Then you should REALLY consider reading document about the MVVM pattern, which will make your life easier with this kind of issue. Finally, the XAML you posted is wrong, there is a closing Grid, without an opening one. Try to paste some valid code first

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: But the question sheridan posted is absolutely not useful about my problem, i have a datatemplate because i need to refresh the screen of on other class and it works perfectely. So the problem is here: i have a class which manages the code behind my resource dictionary, i can handle click events with button but what i want is to get the value of my textbox. Please don't talk me about MVVM it is not the purpose of my exercise, i posted a simple question, i don't need you ask me complicated other questions.